# asymptotic growth of entire functions with positive taylor coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have an entire function $g(x)$ with taylor coefficients that go to zero at a ridiculously fast rate and I am trying to bound it with another entire function $f$ with similar properties but with the added claim that $f(x) \sim x^{1-\epsilon}$ so that I can say $g(x) = o(x)$.

I need the coefficients of $f$ to be positive though. 
For example I was thinking of a function like $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!^{n!}}$$ or something similar which must grow slowly.
I don't know how to prove this though, and was wondering if there was some technique or if another function would work better.